# Not able to add contact us to navigation menu

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation, contact-us

I am trying to put the link of contact us that is at the bottom of magento website on the navigation menu. The form contains email textbox and a textbox where user could write and submit it. I want this link to open from navigation bar at the top. I tried doing it but nothing works.  Please let me know how can I do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can configure to show the information like.

1. Create a static block by Content -> Blocks -> Add new block (In your case copy cms page `about us` content and paste it in your block ) -> Save.
2. Go to Product -> Categories -> Create category by the name you want.
3. Go to Display setting of the category -> Select CMS Block ( in your case select the block as in step 1 ).
4. Display mode should be -> Static Block only.

Save , remove cache and check it in front end menu.

**If you want to render contact us** (Contact form is calling from template)

Create a CMS static block as described on top and paste the below code in Content

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Make sure you select this(saved by above code) static block into category you want to display in Navigation.(Display setting of the category -> Select CMS Block.)

This answer is one of an option for display the information, if you want to add more links with custom information, you can override Navigation section by creating custom module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried this approach, but I cannot find the CMS of contact us page that should be used to put in a block. I want to put the link of contact us that is at the very bottom of the page . It contains field such as name, email address, phone number and whats on your mind text field. Icannot find the CMS block for this page. Could you help me where I can find it?

Comment: for eg. when I open contact us page, the link that shows in my address bar is like
www.mywebsite.com/contact/

Comment: I have modified the answer, feel free to ask if it is not working ..:)

Comment: thanks krishna. it worked.However I wanted to have this contact us page for a different email . I mean the email to which the messages will be delivered should be different form the one at the bottom. Is this possible?

Comment: check this controller vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope

Comment: What do I jave to change over here so that it work for both contact us form but with different emails?

Comment: Hi Krishna, I want this contact us page to populate with the logged in user details such as his name and it should open only on his account. How should I approach this.